# User logged out after viewing entity with ManyToOne relationship

Tags: php, symfony, symfony6, symfony-security

I am new to Symfony and hope you can help me with some security/doctrine relationship issues.

I am using Symfony 6.3.1 with the security bundle and a few other bundles (saml onelogin and knpu oauth2 for authentication, not sure if this is relevant).

My project have 4 entities : **CoreUser**, **CoreAd**, **User** which extends CoreUser, and **Ad** which extends CoreAd. CoreAd has a ManyToOne relationship with User. Yeah it might be a little wonky...

When on my route **app_view_advertisement**, which prints Ad details, the session loses the current user somehow. After reloading the page, an exception is thrown `You cannot refresh a user from the EntityUserProvider that does not contain an identifier` and the current user is logged out. This only happened after adding the ManyToOne relationship.

**CoreUser Entity** :

```
namespace Core\UserBundle\src\Entity;

use Core\UserBundle\src\Entity\Types\EmailType;
use Core\UserBundle\src\Repository\CoreUserRepository;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

#[ORM\MappedSuperclass(repositoryClass: CoreUserRepository::class)]
class CoreUser implements UserInterface, PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface, CoreUserInterface
{
    use ObjectTrait;

    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column]
    private ?int $id = null;

    #[ORM\Column]
    private array $roles = [];

    /**
     * @var string The hashed password
     */
    #[ORM\Column]
    private ?string $password = null;

    #[ORM\Column(type:EmailType::class, length: 512)]
    private ?string $email = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 512, unique: true)]
    private ?string $hashEmail = null;

    public function __construct()
    {
    }

    /**
    * @return int|null
    */
    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * A visual identifier that represents this user.
     *
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function getUserIdentifier(): string
    {
        return $this->hashEmail;
    }

    /**
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function getRoles(): array
    {
        $roles = $this->roles;

        if ($this->getAccountType() == AccountType::SysAdmin) {
            $roles[] = 'ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN';
        }
        else{
            $roles[] = 'ROLE_USER';
        }

        return array_unique($roles);
    }

    /**
    * @param array $roles
    * @return $this
    */
    public function setRoles(array $roles): static
    {
        $this->roles = $roles;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @see PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface
     */
    public function getPassword(): string
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

    /**
    * @param string $password
    * @return $this
    */
    public function setPassword(string $password): static
    {
        $this->password = $password;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function eraseCredentials(): void
    {
        // If you store any temporary, sensitive data on the user, clear it here
        // $this->plainPassword = null;
    }

    /**
    * @return string|null
    */
    public function getEmail(): ?string
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    /**
    * @param string $email
    * @return $this
    */
    public function setEmail(string $email): static
    {
        $this->email = $email;
        $this->hashEmail = EmailType::hash($email);
        return $this;
    }

    /**
    * @return string|null
    */
    public function getHashEmail(): ?string
    {
        return $this->hashEmail;
    }

    /**
    * @param string $hashEmail
    * @return $this
    */
    public function setHashEmail(string $hashEmail): static
    {
        $this->hashEmail = $hashEmail;
        return $this;
    }
}
```

EmailType is a custom Doctrine Type (encrypted email), hashEmail is the identifier which is the hashed email.

**User Entity** :

```
use App\Repository\UserRepository;
use Core\UserBundle\src\Entity\CoreUser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: UserRepository::class)]
class User extends CoreUser
{
}
```

**CodeAd Entity** :

```
namespace Core\AdBundle\src\Entity;

use App\Entity\User;
use Core\UserBundle\src\Entity\CoreUser;
use Core\UserBundle\src\Entity\ObjectTrait;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Types;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\JoinColumn;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Annotation\Groups;

#[ORM\MappedSuperclass]
class CoreAd
{
    use ObjectTrait;

    #[Groups(['extended.item'])]
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column]
    private ?int $id = null;

    #[ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity: User::class)]
    #[JoinColumn(name: 'ownerId', referencedColumnName: 'id')]
    private CoreUser $owner;

    public function __construct()
    {
    }

    /**
    * @return int|null
    */
    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
    * @return CoreUser
    */
    public function getOwner(): CoreUser
    {
        return $this->owner;
    }

    /**
    * @param CoreUser $owner
    * @return CoreAd
    */
    public function setOwner(CoreUser $owner): CoreAd
    {
        $this->owner = $owner;
        return $this;
    }
}
```

**Ad Entity** :

```
namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\AdRepository;
use Core\AdBundle\src\Entity\CoreAd;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: AdRepository::class)]
class Ad extends CoreAd
{
}
```

Login and logout seem to work fine, so I'm not going to copy/paste my security.yaml file or my authenticators, but please let me know if you need them as well.

The ManyToOne relationship between CoreAd and User seems misconfigured, I have an exception when viewing a page with the Ad Entity on my route **app_view_advertisement**, after reloading the page.

**AdController** :

```
namespace Core\AdBundle\src\Controller;

use App\Entity\Ad;
use App\Repository\AdRepository;
use Core\AdBundle\src\Form\AdFormType;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Attribute\IsGranted;

class AdController extends AbstractController
{
    #[Route('/advertisement/add/', name: 'app_add_advertisement')]
    public function add(
        Request $request,
        AdRepository $adRepository
    ): Response
    {
        $this->denyAccessUnlessGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY');

        $advertisement = new Ad();
        $form = $this->createForm(AdFormType::class, $advertisement);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
                    $advertisement->setOwner($this->getUser());

                    $adRepository->save($advertisement, true);
        }

        return $this->render('@CoreAd/advertisement/add.html.twig', [
            'adForm' => $form->createView()
        ]);
    }

    #[IsGranted('view', 'advertisement')]
    #[Route('/advertisement/view/{id}/', name: 'app_view_advertisement')]
    public function view(Ad $advertisement): Response
    {
        return $this->render('@CoreAd/advertisement/view.html.twig', [
            'ad' => $advertisement
        ]);
    }
}
```

The session seems to be losing the current user info on that route.

Without the User entity (attached the current user with `$advertisement->setOwner($this->getUser());`) in the Ad Entity, it works fine.

**AdRepository** :

```
namespace App\Repository;

use App\Entity\Ad;
use Core\AdBundle\src\Repository\CoreAdRepository;
use Doctrine\Persistence\ManagerRegistry;

class AdRepository extends CoreAdRepository
{
    public function __construct(ManagerRegistry $registry)
    {
        parent::__construct($registry, Ad::class);
    }
}
```

**CoreAdRepository** :

```
namespace Core\AdBundle\src\Repository;

use Core\AdBundle\src\Entity\CoreAd;
use Doctrine\Persistence\ManagerRegistry;
use Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Repository\ServiceEntityRepository;

class CoreAdRepository extends ServiceEntityRepository
{
    public function __construct(ManagerRegistry $registry, string $entity = CoreAd::class)
    {
        parent::__construct($registry, $entity);
    }

    public function save(CoreAd $entity, bool $flush = false): void
    {
    $now = new \DateTime('now');

    if (is_null($entity->getCreationDate())) {
        $entity->setCreationDate($now)
            ->setSlug($entity->slugify());
    }

        $entity->setLastModificationDate($now);

        $this->getEntityManager()->persist($entity);

        if ($flush) {
            $this->getEntityManager()->flush();
        }
    }

    public function remove(CoreAd $entity, bool $flush = false): void
    {
        $this->getEntityManager()->remove($entity);

        if ($flush) {
            $this->getEntityManager()->flush();
        }
    }
}
```

The Exception is the following :

```
InvalidArgumentException:
You cannot refresh a user from the EntityUserProvider that does not contain an identifier. The user object has to be serialized with its own identifier mapped by Doctrine.

  at vendor/symfony/doctrine-bridge/Security/User/EntityUserProvider.php:88
  at Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Security\User\EntityUserProvider->refreshUser()
     (vendor/symfony/security-http/Firewall/ContextListener.php:207)
  at Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall\ContextListener->refreshUser()
     (vendor/symfony/security-http/Firewall/ContextListener.php:127)
  at Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall\ContextListener->authenticate()
     (vendor/symfony/security-bundle/Debug/WrappedLazyListener.php:46)
  at Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\Debug\WrappedLazyListener->authenticate()
     (vendor/symfony/security-bundle/Security/LazyFirewallContext.php:73)
  at Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\Security\LazyFirewallContext->Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\Security\{closure}()
     (vendor/symfony/security-core/Authentication/Token/Storage/TokenStorage.php:34)
  at Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\Storage\TokenStorage->getToken()
     (vendor/symfony/security-core/Authentication/Token/Storage/UsageTrackingTokenStorage.php:44)
  at Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\Storage\UsageTrackingTokenStorage->getToken()
     (vendor/symfony/security-core/Authorization/AuthorizationChecker.php:42)
  at Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authorization\AuthorizationChecker->isGranted()
     (vendor/symfony/security-http/EventListener/IsGrantedAttributeListener.php:65)
  at Symfony\Component\Security\Http\EventListener\IsGrantedAttributeListener->onKernelControllerArguments()
     (vendor/symfony/event-dispatcher/Debug/WrappedListener.php:116)
  at Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\Debug\WrappedListener->__invoke()
     (vendor/symfony/event-dispatcher/EventDispatcher.php:220)
  at Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->callListeners()
     (vendor/symfony/event-dispatcher/EventDispatcher.php:56)
  at Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->dispatch()
     (vendor/symfony/event-dispatcher/Debug/TraceableEventDispatcher.php:139)
  at Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\Debug\TraceableEventDispatcher->dispatch()
     (vendor/symfony/http-kernel/HttpKernel.php:161)
  at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw()
     (vendor/symfony/http-kernel/HttpKernel.php:74)
  at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle()
     (vendor/symfony/http-kernel/Kernel.php:197)
  at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->handle()
     (vendor/symfony/runtime/Runner/Symfony/HttpKernelRunner.php:35)
  at Symfony\Component\Runtime\Runner\Symfony\HttpKernelRunner->run()
     (vendor/autoload_runtime.php:29)
  at require_once('/home/perrine/git/BoilerPlate/vendor/autoload_runtime.php')
     (public/index.php:5)
```

Not sure how to fix this :(

I'm fairly new to Symfony and still learning.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I did not analyze this too much, but right off the batt, is it normal that your CoreUser class has a repository?

Answer (score 0):

How does your user repositories look like? Do they implement UserLoaderInterface? And what is configured as identifier field for the entity loader?

I guess that EmailType somehow disturbs the default implementation logic for loading the user entity from database. You maybe need to implement custom logic to fetch users based on their identifier in your user repository. See https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/user_providers.html#using-a-custom-query-to-load-the-user

Comment: Thanks for your help Jan, I reviewed the whole identifier process and found a work around.

After adding a serialize/unserialize method to the CoreUser Entity, the issue disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

After a few more tests, I found a work around. After adding a serialize/unserialize method to the CoreUser Entity, the issue disappeared.

```
    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function __serialize(): array
    {
        return [
            $this->getId(),
            $this->getHashEmail(),
            $this->getPassword()
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @param array $data
     * @return void
     */
    public function __unserialize(array $data): void
    {
        list(
            $this->id,
            $this->hashEmail,
            $this->password
            ) = $data;
    }

    /**
     * @return string[]
     */
    public function __sleep(): array
    {
        return ['id', 'hashEmail', 'password'];
    }
```

However, if anyone has an explanation for this behavior, I'm all ears!